# MSOEngine Objective-C library

Tags: library, iphone, cocoa, mac-os-x, objective-c

**MSOEngine**

Basically MSOEngine (Matt's Stack Overflow Engine) is an Objective-C library that communicates with Stack Overflow.

It uses the MIT License.

You can find (the new and improved version) [here](http://github.com/computermatt/MSOEngine).

This currently runs on ***both*** Mac OS X ***and*** iPhone. The new version has been pushed up to [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub). It works the same was as before, and you don't have to do a thing to make it work with the iPhone OS.

**Sample**

See README in the GitHub link and it explains how to use it. It's a little complex, and requires at least a level 5 in reading documentation.

**Contact**

You can contact me at matt (at) mattsapps (dot) com